# How to use appsrc for sparse audio stream?

Tags: gstreamer, audio-player

I'm trying to set up a simple audio pipeline to play a custom audio stream which is only transmitting data for short amounts of time.

My pipeline looks like this:
`appsrc -> queue -> audioconvert -> audioresample -> pulsesink`

I set the `caps` and `is-live` property of `appsrc`. Nonetheless, the pipeline is stuck does not transition to PLAYING. `push-buffer` events are emitted as soon as some samples arrive over the wire.

```
0:00:17.906937330  1576  0xa4d400 INFO      GST_STATES gstelement.c:2090:gst_element_get_state_func:<pulse0> waiting for element to commit state
0:00:17.907023165  1576  0xa4d400 INFO      GST_STATES gstelement.c:2104:gst_element_get_state_func:<pulse0> timed out
```

A [similar question](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2014-October/050052.html) was asked on gstreamer-devel which indicates that I might need to send GAP events.

Do I have to continuously send buffers? If so, what should be done when the stream is not sending temporarily?

Comment: what happens when you use alsasink?

Comment: additionaly try to use do-timestamp=true .. I guess you do not append PTS manually on the buffers? I have a strong feeling that its same problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38520801/3876138)